# Matplotlib: different stacked bars?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a stacked bar plot with different amount of stacks for each bar. The [general example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html) for stacked bars works fine if my data are all homogenous, but I want something that rather looks like the shown example.

[image: Example: different stacked bars]

This turned out to be whole other level in Matplotlib (while still easy with some Excel-like tool, as you can see). Is there a convenient way of creating this kind of plot in Matplotlib? Thanks.

Comment: Look for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37770099/2666859

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are working directly in matplotlib, but these days plotting data, especially for quick a view can be easily done  with pandas, following your example we get:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use("ggplot")
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series([10,20,40,10,np.nan]), pd.Series([20,10,30,10,10]), pd.Series([30,40, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])], index=["Bar1", "Bar2", "Bar3"])

df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```