# How to plot a stacked bar with annotations for multiple groups

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

In the histogram a gap appears between 2 bars.. anyone knows why?

I get this error:

The number of FixedLocator locations (11), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (10).

The csv file is just 2 columns, one with the name of the country and the other with the type of medal achieved, each line a medal with its type and country.

The link to the file is: https://github.com/jpiedehierroa/files/blob/main/Libro1.csv

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pathlib import Path
my_csv = Path("C:/Usersjosep/Desktop/Libro1.csv")
df = pd.read_csv("Libro1.csv", sep=',')

# or load from github repo link
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpiedehierroa/files/main/Libro1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)    

# Prepare data
x_var = 'countries'
groupby_var = 'type'
df_agg = df.loc[:,[x_var, groupby_var]].groupby(groupby_var)
vals = [df[x_var].values.tolist() for i, df in df_agg]

# Draw
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10), dpi= 100)
colors= ("#CD7F32","silver","gold")
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(vals, df[x_var].unique().__len__(), stacked=True, density=False, color=colors[:len(vals)])

# Decoration
plt.legend(["bronze", "silver","gold"], loc="upper right")
plt.title(f"Histogram of medals achieved by ${x_var}$ colored by ${groupby_var}$ in Tokyo 2020", fontsize=18)
plt.text(2,80,"138")
plt.xlabel(x_var)
plt.ylabel("amount of medals by type")
plt.ylim(0, 130)
plt.xticks(ticks=bins, labels=np.unique(df[x_var]).tolist(), rotation=90, horizontalalignment='left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Test Data

- In case the link dies

```py
countries,type
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,gold
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,silver
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
USA,bronze
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,gold
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,silver
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
China,bronze
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,gold
Japan,silver
Japan,silver
Japan,silver
Japan,silver
Japan,silver
Japan,silver
Japan,silver
Japan,silver
Japan,silver
Japan,silver
Japan,silver
Japan,silver
Japan,silver
Japan,silver
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
Japan,bronze
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,gold
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,silver
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
GB,bronze
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,gold
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,silver
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
ROC,bronze
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,gold
Australia,silver
Australia,silver
Australia,silver
Australia,silver
Australia,silver
Australia,silver
Australia,silver
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Australia,bronze
Netherlands,gold
Netherlands,gold
Netherlands,gold
Netherlands,gold
Netherlands,gold
Netherlands,gold
Netherlands,gold
Netherlands,gold
Netherlands,gold
Netherlands,gold
Netherlands,silver
Netherlands,silver
Netherlands,silver
Netherlands,silver
Netherlands,silver
Netherlands,silver
Netherlands,silver
Netherlands,silver
Netherlands,silver
Netherlands,silver
Netherlands,silver
Netherlands,silver
Netherlands,bronze
Netherlands,bronze
Netherlands,bronze
Netherlands,bronze
Netherlands,bronze
Netherlands,bronze
Netherlands,bronze
Netherlands,bronze
Netherlands,bronze
Netherlands,bronze
Netherlands,bronze
Netherlands,bronze
Netherlands,bronze
Netherlands,bronze
France,gold
France,gold
France,gold
France,gold
France,gold
France,gold
France,gold
France,gold
France,gold
France,gold
France,silver
France,silver
France,silver
France,silver
France,silver
France,silver
France,silver
France,silver
France,silver
France,silver
France,silver
France,silver
France,bronze
France,bronze
France,bronze
France,bronze
France,bronze
France,bronze
France,bronze
France,bronze
France,bronze
France,bronze
France,bronze
Germany,gold
Germany,gold
Germany,gold
Germany,gold
Germany,gold
Germany,gold
Germany,gold
Germany,gold
Germany,gold
Germany,gold
Germany,silver
Germany,silver
Germany,silver
Germany,silver
Germany,silver
Germany,silver
Germany,silver
Germany,silver
Germany,silver
Germany,silver
Germany,silver
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Germany,bronze
Italy,gold
Italy,gold
Italy,gold
Italy,gold
Italy,gold
Italy,gold
Italy,gold
Italy,gold
Italy,gold
Italy,gold
Italy,silver
Italy,silver
Italy,silver
Italy,silver
Italy,silver
Italy,silver
Italy,silver
Italy,silver
Italy,silver
Italy,silver
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
Italy,bronze
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This is easier to implement as a stacked bar plot, as such, reshape the dataframe with [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and plot using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with `kind='bar'` and `stacked=True`

  - This should not be implemented with `plt.hist` because it's more convoluted, and it's easier to use the pandas plot method directly.
  - Also a histogram is more appropriate when the x values are a continuous range of numbers, not discrete categorical values.
- `ct.iloc[:, :-1]` selects all but the last column, `'tot'` to be plotted as bars.
- Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) to add annotations

  - `ax.bar_label(ax.containers[2], padding=3)` uses `label_type='edge'` by default, which results in annotating the edge with the cumulative sum (`'center'` annotates with the patch value), as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70280423/7758804).

    - The `[2]` in `ax.containers[2]` selects only the top containers to annotate with the cumulative sum. The `containers` are 0 indexed from the bottom.
  - See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for additional details and examples
  - This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64202669/7758804) shows how to do annotations the old way, without `.bar_label`. I do not recommend it.
  - This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68785457/7758804) shows how to customize labels to prevent annotations for values under a given size.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.3.5`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`**

### Load and Shape the DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd

# load from github repo link
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpiedehierroa/files/main/Libro1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url) 

# reshape the dataframe
ct = pd.crosstab(df.countries, df.type)

# total medals per country, which is necessary to sort the bars
ct['tot'] = ct.sum(axis=1)

# sort
ct = ct.sort_values(by='tot', ascending=False)

# display(ct)
type         bronze  gold  silver  tot
countries                             
USA              33    39      41  113
China            18    38      32   88
ROC              23    20      28   71
GB               22    22      21   65
Japan            17    27      14   58
Australia        22    17       7   46
Italy            20    10      10   40
Germany          16    10      11   37
Netherlands      14    10      12   36
France           11    10      12   33
```

### Plot

```py
colors = ("#CD7F32", "silver", "gold")
cd = dict(zip(ct.columns, colors))

# plot the medals columns
title = 'Country Medal Count for Tokyo 2020'
ax = ct.iloc[:, :-1].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=cd, title=title,
                          figsize=(12, 5), rot=0, width=1, ec='k' )

# annotate each container with individual values
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center')
    
# annotate the top containers with the cumulative sum
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[2], padding=3)

# pad the spacing between the number and the edge of the figure
ax.margins(y=0.1)
```

[image]

- An alternative way to annotate the top with the sum is to use the `'tot'` column for custom labels, but as shown, this is not necessary.

```py
labels = ct.tot.tolist()
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[2], labels=labels, padding=3)
```