# Stacked bars are unexpectedly annotated with the sum of bar heights

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, plot-annotations

My data:

```
names_col = ['Count','Freq']
dat = [['Matching', 56935],['Mismatching', 100587]]
plot_df = pd.DataFrame(data=dat,columns=names_col)
```

I trying plot stacked catplot with showing values , there is my code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
p=plot_df.set_index('Count').T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
p.bar_label(p.containers[0])
p.bar_label(p.containers[1])
plt.show();
```

First of all, output of figure not in size (16,9), what wrong?
And the second plot show value as:
[image]

instead value for `matching` - 56935 (here its ok), and `mismatching` - 100587, plot show total(157522).
How I can access and show also to `Mismatching` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) twice

  - **The annotation value is being determined based on whether the label is at the center of the bar or the edge of the bar.**
  - The other answer uses `x[0].` because there is only one group of stacked bars, but that won't work if there's more than one group on the x-axis.
  - See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for more details and examples with `.bar_label`.
- Reshaping the dataframe should be a separate step from plotting
- [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) uses `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend, and has a number of parameters like `rot`, `xlabel`, `ylabel`, and `figsize`, for customizing the plot.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.5.0`**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dat, columns=names_col)
dft = df.set_index('Count').T

axe = dft.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(16,9), rot=0)

for x in axe.containers:
    axe.bar_label(x, label_type='edge', weight='bold')
    axe.bar_label(x, label_type='center', weight='bold', color='white')
```

[image]

- Here's a more thorough example with multiple groups

  - The other answer does not place the middle annotations for the second group of bars.

```py
# test data 
data = {'Matching': [56935, 17610], 'Mismatching': [100587, 13794], 'Test': [33139, 23567]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=['Freq', 'Freq2'])

axe = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(16,9), rot=0)

for x in axe.containers:
    axe.bar_label(x, label_type='edge', weight='bold')
    axe.bar_label(x, label_type='center', weight='bold', color='white')
```

[image]

### Add only the total to the top of the bars

- Add a new colon for the sum of the rows, to use for annotations

```
df['tot'] = df.sum(axis=1)

display(df)
       Matching  Mismatching   Test     tot
Freq      56935       100587  33139  190661
Freq2     17610        13794  23567   54971

# plot 
axe = df.iloc[:, :3].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(16,9), rot=0)

# annotate
for x in axe.containers:
    axe.bar_label(x, label_type='center', weight='bold', color='white')

# resuse x from the for loop, the last x is the top set of bar patches
axe.bar_label(x, labels=df['tot'], label_type='edge', weight='bold')
```

[image]

Comment: "The annotation value is being determined based on whether the label is at the center of the bar or the edge of the bar". Didn't know that! that's indeed much cleaner!

Comment: @Tranbi I didn't either. I was playing around with setting the annotations, when I discovered that "feature".

Answer (score 1):

You can set `figsize` as parameter of plot. Then for each of your containers, add the bar label and your own text:

```
p=plot_df.set_index('Count').T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(16,9)) 
for x in p.containers:
    p.bar_label(x)
    p.text(0, x[0].get_y() + x[0].get_height()*0.5, x.datavalues[0], ha='center', color='w', weight='bold')

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]