# Adding data labels ontop of my histogram Python/Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, bar-chart, histogram

i am trying to add data labels values on top of my histogram to try to show the frequency visibly.

This is my code now but unsure how to code up to put the value ontop:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.hist(df['Age'], edgecolor='white', label='d')
plt.xlabel("Age")
plt.ylabel("Number of Patients")
plt.title = ('Age Distrubtion')
```

I was wondering if anyone knows the code to do this:

[image]

Comment: Functionally, a histogram is just a bar plot, so this [Adding value labels on a matplotlib bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804), and similar to [How to plot a stacked bar with annotations for multiple groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69872543/7758804) and [How to plot percentage with seaborn distplot / histplot / displot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63373194/7758804)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib - label each bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352740/matplotlib-label-each-bin)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the new `bar_label()` function using the bars returned by `plt.hist()`.

Here is an example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': np.random.randint(20, 60, 200)})

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
values, bins, bars = plt.hist(df['Age'], edgecolor='white')
plt.xlabel("Age")
plt.ylabel("Number of Patients")
plt.title('Age Distrubtion')
plt.bar_label(bars, fontsize=20, color='navy')
plt.margins(x=0.01, y=0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.hist() with plt.bar_label()]

PS: As the age is discrete distribution, it is recommended to explicitly set the bin boundaries, e.g. `plt.hist(df['Age'], bins=np.arange(19.999, 60, 5))`.

Comment: Note that `bar_label` is available only in matplotlib version 3.4 or later.

Comment: For me, setting the title like this doesn't work. I need something like `fig, ax = plt.subplots(); ax.set_title = ('Age Distrubtion')`

Comment: @Julian Many thanks for pointing out this error.  It seems I just copied that part of the original code without checking it. `plt.title = "..."` is not only not working, it makes the function unreachable afterward.  The correct way would be `plt.title("...")` or `ax.set_title("...")` as you indicated.

Answer (score 2):

The [plt.ylabel()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel.html) comes with a parameter called `loc` that can be used to define a label's position:

```py
plt.ylabel("Age", loc="top")
```

If you want manual control, you can use the `**kwargs` argument to pass in `Text` object ([documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text)) which can take in `x` and `y` co-ordinate values to place text.

```py
plt.ylabel("Age", text(x=100, y=200, rotation='horizontal'))
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your resposne however when i run that code i get the  following error:ValueError: 'top' is not a valid value for loc; supported values are 'left', 'center', 'right'

Comment: @RubenVellupillai I believe you're running the code for `plt.xlabel()` instead of `plt.ylabel()`

Comment: sorry again to ask but i get another error NameError: name 'text' is not defined

Comment: @RubenVellupillai Import the module via `import matplotlib.pyplot.text as text`