# adding labels and normal distribution to a histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have been wrestling with trying to add some extra details to my histogram but none of the solutions seem to work (e.g. [Adding data labels ontop of my histogram Python/Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70416097/adding-data-labels-ontop-of-my-histogram-python-matplotlib)); maybe because my histogram is at the end of a long process (this code works). Any ideas how to add in? I thought it might have to go in def make_plot(): but most solutions have the details a bit different. I also tried to add in ([How to plot a histogram using Matplotlib in Python with a list of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203645/how-to-plot-a-histogram-using-matplotlib-in-python-with-a-list-of-data)) but I think it suffers from the same problem of where to put it in the script. I am new to this so forgive me if it is obvious. Thanks!

```
%matplotlib inline
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




def save_fig(fig_id, tight_layout=True, fig_extension="png", resolution=900):
    path = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, fig_id + "." + fig_extension)
    print("Saving figure", fig_id)
    if tight_layout:
        plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(path, format=fig_extension, dpi=resolution)



def make_plot():
  plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
  df_vaderized['vader_compound'].plot(kind='hist', bins = 15, color='thistle')
  plt.ylabel('Frequency')
  plt.title('t0 sentiment analysis')
  plt.grid(True)
  
  plt.savefig('/content/t0_5.png')

# Just calling the function
make_plot()
```

This doesn't work based off ([Adding data labels ontop of my histogram Python/Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70416097/adding-data-labels-ontop-of-my-histogram-python-matplotlib)). Instead I get AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'bar_label'.

```
def make_plot():
  plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
  values, bins, bars = plt.hist(t0wordcloudtext_df['afinn_adjusted'], bins = 15, edgecolor='white')
  
  plt.bar_label(bars, fontsize=20, color='navy')
  plt.margins(x=0.01, y=0.1)

#  t0wordcloudtext_df['afinn_adjusted'].plot(kind='hist', bins = 15, color='salmon')
  plt.ylabel('Frequency')
  plt.xlabel('Adjusted AFINN')
  plt.title('t0 AFINN sentiment analysis ')
  plt.grid(True)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you tried and in what way it is not working?  In general it is better to figure out what you want on a small program and then add it to the larger one after debugging.

Comment: I added an example of what I tried above. Thanks for looking.

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: I think 3.2.2: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (3.2.2)
I reinstalled matplotlib just in case didn't do anything

Comment: `bar_label` is a new function, starting with matplotlib 3.4

Comment: legend! that script works :)
to download the new version:
!pip install -U pip
!pip install -U matplotlib