# Show previously created pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Say I create a bar plot in a Jupyter notebook:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

speed = [0.1, 17.5, 40, 48, 52, 69, 88]
lifespan = [2, 8, 70, 1.5, 25, 12, 28]
index = ["snail", "pig", "elephant", "rabbit", "giraffe", "coyote", "horse"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"speed": speed, "lifespan": lifespan}, index=index)

plot = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

This shows my chart.

[image]

Then, in the next cell, I make a modification, e.g. adding data labels:

```py
for bar in plot.patches:
    height = bar.get_height()
    width = bar.get_width()
    x = bar.get_x()
    y = bar.get_y()
    label_text = height
    label_x = x + width / 2
    label_y = y + height / 2
    if label_text != 0:
        plot.text(
            label_x,
            label_y,
            int(label_text),
            ha="center",
            va="center",
            color="white",
            fontweight="bold",
        )
```

Now, how can I show the plot again? `plt.show()` returns nothing.

Comment: See [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69873708/7758804) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for easier bar labels using `.bar_label(...)`

Comment: This is the better [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895640/7758804) for labeled stacked bars.

Comment: Thank you! I was using code that I found elsewhere and was the only way I ever saw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just show the figure again:

```
plot.figure
```

[image]

As an alternative, you can use [`plot.get_figure()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.get_figure.html).